# How can I get the whole xml response from SoapFaultClientException

Tags: java, soap, soapfault

I get this exception because response is soapFault. Is there options how I can get whole xml response from this exception ? I need this because important content of this xml inst in  `ex.getFaultStringOrReason()` but as comment at the end of this xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ex.getSoapFault().getSource()` will give you a `Source` which you can then inspect manually or marshall.

(e.g. with `TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source, new StringResult()` then call `toString()` on the StringResult)

Comment: i am not able to understand this.. can anyone please explain me?